# removing milliseconds part from Date object

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, struts2

I am creating a website using struts2,mysql,hibernate(for table to class mapping)

In Mysql value stored is
2012-12-10 00:04:52

After fetching it to a variable "addedDate" i tried printing it

```
class d{
Date addedDate;
}
```

addedDate is 2012-12-10 00:04:52.0

In Hibernate mapping (xml file) i have given

```
<property name="addedDate" type="timestamp">
            <column name="ADDED_DATE" length="19" not-null="true" />
        </property>
```

In the Action class i have created

```
List<d> dList
```

in jsp

```
<s:iterator value="dList" >
<td><s:property value="addedDate" /></td>   
</s:iterator>
```

The output i get on the screen
12/10/12 12:04:52 AM.000

I want to remove the ".000" in my outtput any suggestions please

i tried changing type hibernate xml file to Date 1st then to time. Each time its giving  only time or date but i want both without milliseconds.

1 way would be to create a string variable in class d copy addedate to that string then do modification and show on jsp. In that case i don't know to convert from 24hr to 12 hr format

please suggest me if there is any other way or if u need any clarifications do ask me.Thanks in advance

Comment: Format it, don't just print out the raw object toString.

Comment: <td><s:property value="addedDate" /></td> how can i format in this tag if i remember correctly there is no format attribute in <s:property> tag

Comment: Thanks Dave Newton sometimes i dont get which word to search on google  after seeing the word "format" i googled and got http://deepeshdarshan.wordpress.com/2012/07/13/how-to-format-a-number-using-tag-of-struts-2/ this may not solve my issue but learnt i could use this else.The solution to my problem is posted by RC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [`date`](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.8/docs/date.html) tag.

Sample from the doc (adapted):

```
<s:iterator value="dList" >
    <s:date name="addedDate" format="dd/MM/yyyy" />
</s:iterator>
```

(not tested)

Comment: RC. i know this but see the scenario i am tring to fetch from a list <td><s:property value="addedDate" /></td>  so i cat put the tag which u told inside my list.anyway thanks

Comment: Bingo! thanks RC. "name" i thought would not take the value from dList.addedDate was trying "value="addedDate" and i was getting error "value attribute not found in s:date".thanks a lot for helping was wasting nearly 2-3 hrs time trying something else the simply tried here got the answer.Sorry for telling without trying properly Thanks again dude

Answer (score 0):

As Dave suggested, a [`DateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) is definitely the way to go here.

Piggy-backing off of the already implemented `toString` seems elegant at first, but explicitly formatting your date for display to the user interface will be much more readable, stable and less error prone as your code grows. As you can see, you're already getting different behavior when you print it using `System.out` and when you ask JSP to 'print' it for you.

For what you want to do, a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) will do the trick. To boot, it's JavaDocs have a great explanation of how it works and a bunch of examples also.

To give a man a fish...

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
Date now = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
System.out.println(formatter.format(now));
```

will print:

```
12/15/2012 05:39:13 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

If u r Hibernate then use the following annotation it only Stores date in the Database

```
@Column(name="BIRTH_DATE")
    @Temporal (TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date birthDate;
```